The tangential connection is invariant under rigid motions of $\mathbb{R}^n$
This is Problem 4-1 (b) from Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds (2nd Edition).
Preliminary Definitions
On $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define a connection as follows: for any $p\in \mathbb{R}^n, v \in T_p \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y=Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$\displaystyle \begin{equation} \bar{\nabla}_{v}Y = v(Y^i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \tag*{} \end{equation} $
That is, we take the directional derivative of each component. This is is called the Euclidean connection.
Using this connection, we can define a connection on an embedded submanifold $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\pi^{\top}:T\mathbb{R}^n|_{M}\to TM$ be the orthogonal projection of tangent vectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto  the tangent vectors in $M$. Then, for any $p\in M, v\in T_p M$ and $Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$,
$\displaystyle \begin{equation} \nabla^{\top}_{v}Y = \pi^{\top}(\nabla_{v}\bar{Y})\tag*{} \end{equation} $
Here, $\tilde{Y}\in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is any smooth extension of $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Problem 4-1 (a) is about proving that the definition does not depend on the extension.) This connection is called the tangential connection.
Problem Statement
Now, our problem is as follows:

Show that $\nabla_{v}^{\top}Y$ is invariant under rigid motions of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in the following sense: if $F\in \text{E}(n)$ and $\tilde{M}=F(M)$, then $dF_P(\nabla_{v}^{\top}Y)=\nabla_{dF_p(v)}^{\top}(F_*Y)$.

Here, $\text{E}(n)$ is the Euclidean group, i.e., the isometry group on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I don't know what $\tilde{M}$ means here.
I want to solve this problem, but I haven't succeeded.
My Attempt
I thought about calculating $dF_p(\nabla_v \tilde{Y})$ in coordinates. Writing the definition $\bar{\nabla}_{v}\tilde{Y} = v(\tilde{Y}^i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $, we have
$\displaystyle \begin{equation} dF_p(\nabla_{v}\tilde{Y}) = v(\tilde{Y}_i) \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\end{equation}\tag*{}$
by the standard formulas. However, I don't know what else to do. Since we specifically use isometries, metrics have to appear somewhere, but I don't know how.
